# How to use same Choices for all Questions in Django's Polls app

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Sub: Django Poll Project.

---

There can anyone please help me understand to use same set of choices against all questions. I don't want to add choices every time for each question, instead I want to add question with date- time stamp and want that choices which are already added should reflect for my questions and I select any of those choices and vote.

2nd Option I want to work is if I want to add another choice it should allow but it should show all other choices against my question.

Thank You

Rishipal

Comment: Hello Rishipal,
You might want to add some code to your question.
Show us, what you have come up with so far. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way its much easier to see, what you have tried already and where you might need some help.

Comment: Hello Lukover, I want to use choices model to reflect my choices (which are registered as choices), I dont want to change choices, however questions will change. Code for choices and questions model is as follows

Comment: `class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

`

Comment: `class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text`